# How did Sugimoto get downstairs so fast?

Tags: golden-kamuy

In the [S4E1](https://youtu.be/Aj1j36Lc22Y?t=54) of Golden Kamuy, after kicking down Sugimoto, Vasily rushed downstairs, leaving Sugimoto behind. Then Vasily was trying to escape out of the house when he was suddenly grabbed by Sugimoto from behind a shoji.

[image]

How did Sugimoto get downstairs so fast and ahead of Vasily?